# javac 11 to 17 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: java

I've recently tried to update java from sdk11 to sdk17.
For that I've ran:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk
```

and set `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64`.
The problem is that I'm not sure how to update javac...
Currently I only have 1 version, the 11th.

```
java -version
openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.5+8-Ubuntu-2ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.5+8-Ubuntu-2ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)

javac -version
javac 11.0.17
```

Whenever, I compile a program in java it follows JDK11 instead of JDK17...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The javac executable is not part of the *openjdk-*-jdk* packages. To install it, you need to install the *openjdk-17-jdk-headless* package:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk-headless
```

To manage the active version, don't forget about the update-alternatives command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Comment: Many thanks ! It worked. ;)